# can I upload an app onto google play store and make it available for free to the users without using Admob

Tags: google-play-services

I just wanted to know if we can upload an android app on to google play store and make it available to the users for free, without using Admob.

thank you.

Comment: yes. you can upload app for free without using admob

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I would like to know How much should I pay every month to google to put the app in play store

Comment: It's just a one-time $25 USD fee. You can publish an indefinite number of applications. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html). AdMob is just an ad service that allows **you** as the developer to monetize your app, _not_ Google.